# Создание блоков по циклу Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

я получаю JSON данные, в них есть список. Никак не могу понять, как сделать цикл по списку который будет создавать в MainActivity блоки с данными из каждого элемента списка. Проблема в самой реализации блоков. И какой это должен быть элемент в layout.

P.S. C разработкой под Android на Kotlin мало знаком

[image: Example]

Comment: "как сделать цикл по списку", покажите код, что за список? Добавьте в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1319768/edit). Элемент в layout это может быть `TextView` внутри `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Думаю вам стоит использовать RecyclerView